# Popup to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

My Popup partial view:

```
@using StudiModel
@model StudiModel.StudiCommentsPopup
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TopNavLayout.cshtml";
}
@Model.MessageUser
 foreach (var item in Model.CommentsList)
    {
      @item.CommentText
    }
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="input-control textarea" data-role="input-control" style="width: 85%">
                           @Html.TextArea("Message", new { @placeholder = "Add a comment", id = "Comment", style = "width:720px" })
                       </div>
    <input type="button" id="postComment" value="Add a Comment" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.PMessageId)//Why can't I put this here, because I want to pass the text and this id to controller
}
```

I need a jquery to post values into controller and close itself when add button is clicked, and how do I pass two values into jquery?
Thanks

My controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
 //jquery shoul get me two values, id and text box value
  public ActionResult PostComments(string parentMsgId,string Comment)
  {
      StudiMessageDetails comment = new StudiMessageDetails();
       var balObject = new BusinessLogic();
       //comment.UserId = (StudiUserInfoViewModel)Session["UserInfo"].
       comment.MessageId = parentMsgId;
       comment.CommentText = Comment;
       comment.UserId = ((StudiUserInfoViewModel)Session["UserInfo"]).UserId;    
       var message = balObject.AddComment(comment).Message;
      return View();
  }
```

Well, I need a jquery in my partial view to pass the values to my controller..Its .Net..
To open the popup partial view I used:

```
<span class="list-subtitle"><span class="place-right icon-flag-2 fg-red  smaller" onclick="ShowMessage('@item.MessageId');">23
</span>
```

and jquery:

```
<script>
  function ShowMessage(msgid) {
      $.Dialog({
          overlay: false,             
          shadow: true,
          flat: false,
          title: 'Studidesk - Conversations',
          content: '',
          onShow: function (_dialog) {
              var html = [
                  '<iframe width="800" height="480" src="/Channel/Comments?msgid=' + msgid + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
              ].join("");
              $.Dialog.content(html);
          }
      });          
  }
```

Comment: This isn't all jQuery. (Is that .NET/C#?) You should add the appropriate tags

Comment: I'm confused - You say you want to use jquery to pass the values to your controller, but you have a form in the View - which approach do you want to use? The form would probably be easier as you have the code already!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#postComment').on('click', function () {
  var txtComment=$("#Comment").val();
  var hidId=$("#PMessageId").val();
  window.location.href = "Mycontroller/postComment?parentMsgId="+hidId+"&Comment="+txtComment+";
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.